# Images only loading after re-running (Flutter)

Tags: iphone, image, flutter, assets, hot-reload

When loading my flutter app on my IOS device in the android developer IDE, the app loads as normal, but images are not loaded onto the app until I click the "Run 'main.dart'" button again. Once my device is disconnected from my computer and I restart the app, the images never load.

The only advice I can find on anything close to this is "Your yaml file must be wrong". I assure you I've checked my pubspec yaml half a million times and cannot find any errors. Besides, the images DO load when the phone is connected to my computer, but only after running the app a second time after it's installed and run the first time. Any help is much appreciated!! My pubspec.yaml file and flutter doctor -v output are below. Thanks again!

PUBSPEC.YAML:

```
name: billsplitter
description: Split bills easily between your friends!

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  intro_slider: ^2.2.9

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - ./images/Welcome to Bill.jpg
    - ./images/bill description.jpg
    - ./images/bill description2.jpg
    - ./images/bill description3.jpg

  fonts:
    - family: Suez
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/SuezOne-Regular.ttf
```

FLUTTER DOCTOR -V:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/calebburbach/Documents/development/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (6 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/calebburbach/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Try removing the spaces in the file names.  What code are you using to display the images?  Have you checked the console for other errors when running the app when they do not show the first time?  It could be that you don't have the correct layout for them to display.

Answer (score 0):

Change name of image file in images directory and in `pubspec.yaml` file like this:

```
assets:
    - images/welcome_to_Bill.jpg
    - images/bill_description.jpg
    - images/bill_description2.jpg
    - images/bill_description3.jpg
```

Then run this command `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining each image, you can just provide the folder path like this:

```
    assets:
        - images/
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the initState() function? There might be a missing setState() call in one of the load function.

```
setState() {
   // You can initialize a list here, if you have a list that images use.
}
```

This solved the issue when I tried adding elements to the list in setState() function while loading.